# Create combinations of text and transforming these to binary in VBA

Tags: vba, text, binary, combinations

I'm working on a project where I need to combine 6 keywords to the maximum number of combinations. After this is done, I have to transform these combinations to a form of binary.
example:

```
Word1 = 100000  
Word2 = 010000  
Word3 = 001000  
Word4 = 000100  
Word5 = 000010    
Word6 = 000001
```

And a combination could be:  `(Word1 Word2 Word5) = 110010`

My 6 keywords are in column A2:A7.

If this could be done in VBA, it would make my job a lot easier.
Acording to basic math, 6 entries would combine to 64 combinations. I don't need the "blank" combination, why it'll total 63 combinations.
I'm fairly new to coding and have only worked in VBA for a couple of weeks, so I'm hoping that there might be a specialist out there that could help me with this problem.

Update!
This is what I have written so far. It only combines the words once:

```
Sub combinations()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, n As Long, m As Long, lr As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            For j = i + 1 To lr
                For k = j + 1 To lr
                    For l = k + 1 To lr
                        For n = l + 1 To lr
                            For m = n + 1 To lr
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(j, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(k, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(l, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(n, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(m, 1).Value
                            Next m
                        Next n
                    Next l
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Regards,
Emil

Comment: What is "a combination"? Using your example, the keywods 1010101, 1110011, 0110111 cannot be combined without lossing information.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie 
A combination of words.  
I can see now that I might been a little unclear about my task.  
A combination is a combination of the words. Eg. (Word1 Word3 Word4) or (Word1 Word6).  
The 101100 is the binary code that I wish to create after the combinations have been created. So that the combination refers to the number.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to begin with the bitmap representation (BTW it would be best to avoid calling those "binary")

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, i
i = 1
For a = 0 To 1
For b = 0 To 1
For c = 0 To 1
For d = 0 To 1
For e = 0 To 1
For f = 0 To 1
    Cells(i, 1).Value = "'" & a & b & c & d & e & f
    i = i + 1
Next f
Next e
Next d
Next c
Next b
Next a
```